# KnockoutJS: Help me organize multiple viewModels

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am having hell of a time organizing my JS file with multiple viewModels. It is a complete mess and I keep getting errors about binding multiple times, despite having read and tried every trick possible.

Here is my situation: I have 3 view models. 2 of them make ajax request on load. I have also added the `stopBinding` handler so i can bind multiple viewModels in the same page. It works... somewhat. I would also like to figure a way to share functions between viewModels. `isDirty()` in particular (described here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html)

My file is quiet large, so I will post an example. Everything was implemented according to http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html

**JS**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinding = {
    init: function() {
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.stopBinding = true;

// viewModelOne
$.getJSON('/admin/getusers.json', function(json, status) {

    var viewModelOne = ko.mapping.fromJS(json);

    // MODE CODE AND FUNCTIONS HERE. SOME OF THEM ARE 
    // THE SAME AS viewModelTwo USES

   ko.applyBindings(viewModelOne, $('#users-section')[0])

});


// viewModelTwo
$.getJSON('/admin/getdeployments.json', function(json, status) {

    var viewModelTwo = ko.mapping.fromJS(json);

    // MODE CODE AND FUNCTIONS HERE. SOME OF THEM ARE 
    // THE SAME AS viewModelOne USES

    ko.applyBindings(viewModelTwo, $('#deployments-section')[0])

});


// viewModelThree
var viewModelThree = {
    someFunction: function() {
       // SOME CODE HERE
    }

}
ko.applyBindings(viewModelThree, $('#logs-section')[0]);
```

**HTML**

```
<section>

    <!-- ko stopBinding: true -->
    <div id="deployments-section">
         // HTML HERE
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko stopBinding: true -->
    <div id="users-section">
        // HTML HERE
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko stopBinding: true -->
    <div id="logs-section">
        // HTML HERE
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->

</section>
```

1. I do not really need the `viewModelTwo` (the `user.json` data) to load on initial load, just when i click on a particular link, so the only data I need right away is `viewModelOne` (`getdeployments.json` data).
2. I would like to share some functions between viewModels
3. For some strange reason things break if i do `ko.applyBindings(viewModelOne)` to bind this viewModel to the entire document and remove `<!-- ko stopBinding --><!-- /ko -->` around `<div id="deployments-section"></div>`. It only works the way I posted above.
4. I get an error about multiple bindings here `ko.applyBindings(viewModelOne, $('#users-section')[0])`. Adding `ko.cleanNode($('#users-section'))` does not help. I only get the error from this one particular binding, but not the other two.

I guess I'm open to consolidate everything into a single viewModel, if thats a better approach

Comment: If you can, I'd recommend using durandaljs to manage your view models.  It also give you events on when the view gets bound, loaded, etc.  http://durandaljs.com/

Comment: @JasonHaley: Thank you for the suggestion. I will definitely look into it and perhaps use it in my next project, but right now I would like to get this one working without having go back and re-write half of my code. I'm way too deep into this project to introduce any new components into it. Plus I am not really a developer, just working on this to make my life at work a bit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about get rid of stopBinding and go back to basic.

**Javascript**

```
var vm = {
    viewModelOne: ko.observable(),
    viewModelTwo: ko.observable(),
    viewModelThree: {
        someFunction: function() { /* ... */ }
    }
};

var shared_functions = {
    func1: function() { /* use "this" pointer as if it's object viewModelOne or viewModelTwo */ },
    func2: function() {}
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);

// viewModelOne
$.getJSON('/admin/getusers.json', function(json, status) {
    var viewModelOne = ko.mapping.fromJS(json);

    // MODE CODE AND FUNCTIONS HERE.

    // add shared functions too
    $.extend(viewModelOne, shared_functions);
    vm.viewModelOne(viewModelOne);
});

// viewModelTwo
$.getJSON('/admin/getdeployments.json', function(json, status) {

    var viewModelTwo = ko.mapping.fromJS(json);

    // MODE CODE AND FUNCTIONS HERE.

    // add shared functions too
    $.extend(viewModelTwo, shared_functions);
    vm.viewModelTwo(viewModelTwo);

});
```

**HTML**

```
<section>

  <div id="deployments-section" data-bind="with: viewModelTwo">
     // HTML HERE
  </div>

  <div id="users-section" data-bind="with: viewModelOne">
    // HTML HERE
  </div>

  <div id="logs-section" data-bind="with: viewModelThree">
    // HTML HERE
  </div>

</section>
```

If you want some framework level support, besides durandaljs (which I never tried), there is smaller http://pagerjs.com which supports me really well on middle scale knockout web apps.